# What values can the MSBuild output TaskParameter take?

Tags: msbuild

In an MSBuild script, I have the following:

```
<Target Name="CompileCode">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionPath)" Targets="Build" Properties="...">
        <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="Binaries" />
    </MSBuild>
</Target>
```

The output of this target will be a collection `Binaries` which contains all the assemblies *from my project*. I'd like to include *all* assemblies, including external libraries that I've referenced (such as NUnit or Castle.Core). For that, I Imagine there is another value I should set for the `TaskParameter` - but which one?

I'd like to know of *all* the available options here, not just the ones that applies to my specific case - there are other things in this build script that might be eaiser (or even no longer impossible) if I know all my options...

So, **what can I put in the TaskParameter property?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `<Output />` targets output, valid values for the `TaskParameter` property would be any [readable parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) of the `<MSBuild />` task.

The solution for your problem at hand will be to ensure that the projects in your solution specify to copy all referenced assemblies, i.e. the property **CopyLocal** is set to `true` for every referenced assembly you want to receive in `Binaries` (via *TargetOutputs*).

Comment: Which version of VS? Maybe try switching between `true` and `false` to be sure not to fall prey to the ["CopyLocal Bug"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2009/11/18/the-copy-local-bug-in-visual-studio.aspx). Otherwise it should include your referenced assembly in TargetOutputs.

Comment: I'm using VS2010, but the build script is run on a CI server running TeamCity 6.0.3.

Comment: I have now verified that it's **not** the CopyLocal Bug that's causing my problems - it's the fact that the referenced assemblies aren't part of the task parameter. However, as this answers my question ("What are valid values for `TaskParameter`?") I'll mark it as the answer anyway.